# Javascript Promises and updating variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, promise

I've been messing with a way to sign in to Spotify and perform *most* data retrieval from a service in my Ionic app, but a promise is causing the code to pause entirely.

Here is the relevant section from `Controllers.js`:

```
  $scope.tracks = [];

  $scope.getTracks = function () {
    var tracks = {},
            i;
        for (i = 0; i < Tracks.uris.length; i++) {
            console.log('Getting Track ' + i);
            tracks[i] = SpotifyService.getTrack(Tracks.uris[i].id, Tracks.uris[i].loved, Tracks.uris[i].from);
        }
        return tracks;
  }

  $scope.refresh = function () {
    console.log('Refresh Tracks Started');
    $scope.tracks = $scope.getTracks().then(function (data) {
      console.log('Getting tracks');
      return data;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
    $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
  }
```

The `$scope.refresh()` function occurs on a pull to refresh action. This function is called fine, but it stops after the first `console.log()`. Here is an excerpt from the console (with other loggings):

```
2016-04-07 14:30:38.419 HelloCordova[8269:377355] updateInfo() data: [object Object]
2016-04-07 14:30:38.419 HelloCordova[8269:377355] Done updating
2016-04-07 14:30:38.419 HelloCordova[8269:377355] getUser() data: [object Object]
2016-04-07 14:30:38.420 HelloCordova[8269:377355] $scope.load() data: [object Object]
2016-04-07 14:30:41.198 HelloCordova[8269:377355] Refresh Tracks Started
```

After the last line, nothing else happens and the app is left hanging. Ignore the above lines, they're to do with an earlier problem.

I'm not sure what's happening, it's supposed to retrieve some track data from Spotify, but that logic is all called from within the `$scope.getTracks()` function which is never called. What have I done wrong?

**Edit:** Here's the `SpotifyService.getTrack` function from `Services.js`:

```
getTrack: function(id, loved, from) {
    var storedToken = window.localStorage.getItem('spotify-token');
    if (storedToken !== null) {
      return trackInfo(id).then(function(data) {
          return data;
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    } else {
      login();
    }
  }
```

Comment: You'r calling .then on tracks, wich is an object with key as index like an array, something smells bad here.

Comment: I think `SpotifyService.getTrack` is the one returning promises. `$scope.getTracks` is synchronous (returns your array, not a promise).

Comment: I'll add the `SpotifyService.getTrack` function for a little more clarity...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `SpotifyService.getTrack` returns a promise, the `$scope.getTracks` function returns an array of promises. I think what you're looking for, is to assign `$scope.tracks` once all tracks have been received. Try this:

```
$q.all($scope.getTracks()).then(function (data) {
  console.log('Getting tracks');
  $scope.tracks = data;
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```